# Runtime error '13': Type mismatch while using FIND function

Tags: vba

I am using the below code snippet to retrieve a value from my "Data Summary" sheet and find that data in "QG Summary" sheet, if there exists a match I retrieve the data stored in the first column of "QG Summary" sheet for the row identified by my aCell variable.

```
Dim str1 As String
Dim aCell As Range

str1 = Worksheets("Data Summary").Cells(aCell.Row, 3).Value

If (str1 <> "") Then

    Set aCell = Worksheets("QG Summary").Columns(3).Find(What:=str1 _
            , LookIn:=xlValues, LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
            SearchDirection:=xlNext, MatchCase:=False)

    If Not aCell Is Nothing Then
        str1 = Worksheets("QG Summary").Cells(aCell.Row, 1).Value
    End If

End If
```

This code works fine for all case except for cases where my variable str1 has a big value (326 characters). When my str1 variable comes across a big value, this code breaks with a Runtime error '13': Type mismatch. Why?

Comment: On what line does the error occur?

Comment: Yeah string longer than 255 characters will give that problem. Let me search if there is an explanation or bug report for this.

Comment: Perhaps [this](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/213841) can explain it :)

Comment: Jean,

The error occurs while executing "Find".

Comment: Thanks Siddharth for your help. I think the work around then would to split the string into parts less than 255 character in length and maybe then do a find.

Answer (score 1):

As Siddharth Rout says, it's likely related to the character limit of the "What" parameter of `Find`.  I realize your question is worded to ask "Why doesn't this work", but I thought you might be interested in some alternative ways of implementing the same functionality to avoid having to work around that issue.

Dang... I was going to suggest the option of using Excel formulas like so, `=INDEX(Sheet2!$A$2:$C$8, MATCH(Sheet1!A3,Sheet2!$C$2:$C$8,0), 1)`, but I just tested it and apparently the `MATCH` function suffers from the same character limit issue.

Well, another alternative which DOES work in this case is to search the column yourself by checking each cell value in the range.  Comparing strings this way isn't subject to the same constraints as the built-in Excel functions.  Because it's searching the entire column, it will look at the header of that column as well, the same as your original code, so be aware of that.  You can check the value of `foundMatch` to see if a match was found before using the value of `strResult`.  I hardcoded the value 2 for the row on my example lookup of `Worksheets("Data Summary")` - your code has aCell.Row, which hasn't been defined yet, so I assume it has been set by a part of your code that isn't in the snippet.

```
Dim strLookup As String
Dim strResult As String
Dim aCell As Range
Dim foundMatch As Boolean

strLookup = Worksheets("Data Summary").Cells(2, 1).Value

foundMatch = False

If (strLookup <> "") Then
    For Each aCell In Worksheets("QG Summary").Columns(3).Cells
        If aCell.Value = strLookup Then
            strResult = Worksheets("QG Summary").Cells(aCell.Row, 1).Value
            foundMatch = True
            Exit For
        End If
    Next
End If
```